# _beginthread and WaitForSingleObject

Tags: c, windows

I am implementing a program that launches 4 threads.

The functions are:

```
void* SOURCE_in(struct SOURCE_1*);
void* SOURCE_out(struct SOURCE*);
void* SINK_out(struct SINK_1*);
void* SINK_in(struct SINK*);
```

The functions allow communication between 4 blocks.
The Block 1 communicates with block 2.
Block 2 share information with third block.
Block 3 communicates information with the Block 4.

My problem is in main.c

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    extern int p, e_source, e_sink_1, l_sink, l_source_1, flag, ctr_source;
    extern int ctr_source_1, ctr_sink, ctr_sink1;

        SOURCE source;      /*C struct*/
        SINK sink;          /*C struct*/
        SOURCE_1 source_1;  /*C struct*/
        SINK_1 sink_1;      /*C struct*/

        HANDLE CHT[4];

        p = 0;
        e_source =  flag = 0;
        l_sink = e_sink_1 = l_source_1 = 1;
        max = 5;
        ctr_source = ctr_source_1 = ctr_sink = ctr_sink_1 = 0;

        /*Initialize FIFO*/
        F *f1 = fifo_init(10);
        F *f2 = fifo_init(10);

        /*Connect FIFO and modules*/
        source.output_source = f1;
        sink.input_sink = f1;

        sink_1.output_sink = f2;
        source_1.input_source = f2;

        /*Create Threads*/
        CHT[0] = (HANDLE)_beginthread((void (*)(void *))&SOURCE_out, 0, &f1);
        CHT[1] = (HANDLE)_beginthread((void (*)(void *))&SINK_in, 0, &f1);
        CHT[2] = (HANDLE)_beginthread((void (*)(void *))&SINK_out, 0, &f2);
        CHT[3] = (HANDLE)_beginthread((void (*)(void *))&SOURCE_in, 0, &f2);

        /* Wait until all threads have terminated */

        WaitForSingleObject(CHT[0], INFINITE);
        WaitForSingleObject(CHT[1], INFINITE);
        WaitForSingleObject(CHT[2], INFINITE);
        WaitForSingleObject(CHT[3], INFINITE);

        getchar();

        return 0;}
```

I read that WaitForSingleObject function does not work with _beginthread....
But my functions are not the type nunsigned __stdcall...

I build the programm withou errors, and I use breakpoints to test it and it was ok.
when I compile I have this problem:

The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x11ec) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x918) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x8a4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2a8) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x12f8) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[3984] SW=SW.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).

The program never gets to the function getchar()

Before doing this program, I made a program that made communication between two blocks, one read and the other one write. In that case, I had no problems.

If I don not use the function WaitForSingleObject the problem disappears, but my program, almost all times, stops before finishing.

The function that each thread use, stops with a break.
But i want the other ones to continue until its break apear..

Comment: No problem is evident in the output, you just typed Ctrl+C to stop the program.  WaitForSingleObject() isn't reliable with _beginthread() but it will certainly work in most cases.  Preventing your code from reaching getchar().  Looks like at least one of your threads doesn't have an exit condition, we can't see it.

Comment: When I don´t use the function WaitForSingleObject, the progam it´s ok. However, it does not work well. I think the main thread terminates before the return of the child thread functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of [`_beginthread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx) explains that you cannot use one of the wait functions:

> The following sample code demonstrates how you can use the thread handle returned by _beginthreadex with the synchronization API WaitForSingleObject. The main thread waits for the second thread to terminate before it continues. When the second thread calls _endthreadex, it causes its thread object to go to the signaled state. This allows the primary thread to continue running. This cannot be done with _beginthread and _endthread, because _endthread calls CloseHandle, destroying the thread object before it can be set to the signaled state.

And this text also gives you the solution, namely to use `_beginthreadex` instead.

I think you are alluding to this in the question when you say that

> but my functions are not __stdcall

You simply have to change your functions to use the `__stdcall` calling convention.

Comment: Hi, how can I change the function void* SOURCE_in(struct SOURCE_1*) to a _srdcall?

Comment: `void* __stdcall SOURCE_in(struct SOURCE_1*)`

Comment: it does not work... The function should be: unsigned ( __stdcall *start_address )( void * )..

Comment: Then change the return type to match the required prototype

Comment: the return type is different and the argument list is different too

Comment: You don't get a choice. You have to use matching prototype. Adapt your interface to that of beginthreadex

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but you might want to try. I think WaitForSingleObject works only with Windows API. Thus you need to create the threads using `CreateThread` (you can search tge MSDN for the API, it's slightly more complicated than beginthread but not by much, most of the unfamiliar structs can be set to NULL, if you are not into security and the like). CreateThread returns a handle you can wait on.

I think `beginthread` returns something that you can't wait on, that is, the behavoiur of WaitForSingleObject will be undefined. In this case it might just wait forever, and because of  this getchar is not called.

Comment: When I use CreateThread, I have an error becuase of the struct in the argument list.